# How to find and delete files older than specific days in unix?

Tags: find

I have got one folder for log with 7 folders in it. Those seven folders too have subfolders in them and those subfolders have subfolders too. I want to delete all the files older than 15 days in all folders including subfolders without touching folder structrure, that means only files.

```
mahesh@inl00720:/var/dtpdev/tmp/ > ls
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7

mahesh@inl00720:/var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/ > ls
B1 B2 B3 B4 file1.txt file2.csv
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You could start by saying `find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15`.
This will find all files older than 15 days and print their names.
Optionally, you can specify `-print` at the end of the command,
but that is the default action.
It is advisable to run the above command first,
to see what files are selected.

After you verify that the `find` command is listing the files
that you want to delete (and no others),
you can add an "action" to delete the files.
The typical actions to do this are:

1. `-exec rm -f {} \;` (or, equivalently, `-exec rm -f {} ';'`)
   This will run `rm -f` on each file; e.g.,

   ```
   rm -f /var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/B1; rm -f /var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/B2; rm -f /var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/B3; …
   ```
2. `-exec rm -f {} +`
   This will run `rm -f` on many files at once; e.g.,

   ```
   rm -f /var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/B1 /var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/B2 /var/dtpdev/tmp/A1/B3 …
   ```

   so it may be slightly faster than option 1. 
   (It may need to run `rm -f` a few times if you have thousands of files.)
3. `-delete`
   This tells `find` itself to delete the files, without running `rm`.
   This may be infinitesimally faster than the `-exec` variants,
   but it will not work on all systems.

So, if you use option 2, the whole command would be:

```
find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: Using -delete is simpler (syntax and no child processes spawned to do delete) but may not work on all systems. rm -f {} + is best, it will delete files in batches if there are enough files to be too much for one command-line. rm -f {} ';' will give command too long error if there are enough files to be too much for one command-line.

Comment: How does the `-exec rm -f {} +` version handle files with spaces in the name?   Could an attacker craft a filename that would cause this to delete something you didn't want deleted?

Comment: @pileofrogs It passes the filenames directly on as arguments to `rm`. So it's completely safe no matter what characters the filenames contain.

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be to pipe the output from `find` command and use `xargs` to delete those:

```
find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15 | xargs rm
```

But the upvoted answer from Jan still more valid than this one.

Comment: To list and verify first `-ls`:
`find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15 -ls`


To delete `-delete`:
`find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15 -delete`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
find /path/to/files/  -cmin +240  -type f -name *.php  -delete
```

OR

```
find /path/to/files/ -type f -name *.php  -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

The first will delete files 4 hours old or older using the built-in delete function of `find`; and the second will delete files 30 days old or older using an `rm` within an `-exec` clause.

Comment: 1. The OP asked "I want to delete all the files older than 15 days", which your answer doesn't provide. They also did not ask for a restriction to php files. 2. Please use the {} formatting tool to format code as code. 3. If that is your blogspot page, please indicate ownership explicitly, instead of the generic "below link", otherwise you become suspect of simply spamming your site.

Answer (score -2):

Or do it with a loop:

```
for x in $(find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15); do rm "$x"; done
```

Comment: This will not work with files with spaces in them.

Comment: You can use a while loop instead which should take care of files with spaces.

find /var/dtpdev/tmp/ -type f -mtime +15 | while read x; do rm "$x"; done

Answer (score -3):

I like

```
rm -rf `find yadi`
```

for its simplicity.  Those back ticks say "execute me first".  So you are running `rm -rf` against the results of whatever is between them.

Comment: What is `yadi`?

Comment: doesn't work with irregular filenames like containing spaces etc